# Speed up many installations of node modules

Tags: performance, node.js, npm

I wrote a package that analyzes the structure of many yeoman generators:
https://github.com/tobiasoberrauch/yeoman-analyzer

Therefore I have to install all generators. This solution tooks very long (12 hours). I'm not quite sure is the current solution is the best way to do this:

1. Get the list of generator names: https://github.com/tobiasoberrauch/yeoman-analyzer/blob/master/lib/analyzer/data/generators.json
2. Install generators to node_modules regarding a list of generator names (VERY SLOW) : https://github.com/tobiasoberrauch/yeoman-analyzer/blob/master/lib/analyzer/generators.js#L24
3. Analyze the index.js from each generator: https://github.com/tobiasoberrauch/yeoman-analyzer/blob/master/lib/analyzer/generators.js#L47
4. Write report to a json file: https://github.com/tobiasoberrauch/yeoman-analyzer/blob/master/lib/analyzer/reporter/json.js#L21

Is there a way to speed up the process? 2. tooks very long.
I read about caching, local registry (npmd) but I didn't found a proper, fesiable solution.

I would be very happy about any hint :+1: 
Cheers Tobias

Comment: Use `npm install` with the `--production` option. This will make it ignore the `devDependencies`, which usually are not not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need `index.js` only, you don't have to install all generators. Just download a tarball from npm registry using something like wget, and unpack it with `tar xz`.

Comment: Cant a package make `main` anything they want, not just `index.js` ?

Comment: Well, it's an extremely bad style, and they kinda deserve it. :)  But you're right, the program should unpack package.json to check `main` first.

Comment: Besides, the question specifically asks about index.js in #3, so I answered accordingly.

Comment: Trying to add context to the Googlers :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints.
Here's my (temporarily) solution:

1. Get package data from registry: https://github.com/tobiasoberrauch/yeoman-analyzer/blob/master/lib/analyzer/generators.js#L50
2. Get latest version: https://github.com/tobiasoberrauch/yeoman-analyzer/blob/master/lib/analyzer/generators.js#L64
3. Download and / or extract tarball file: https://github.com/tobiasoberrauch/yeoman-analyzer/blob/master/lib/analyzer/generators.js#L129
4. Read package.json from extracted file and get main file: https://github.com/tobiasoberrauch/yeoman-analyzer/blob/master/lib/analyzer/generators.js#L79
5. Find expressions in main file: https://github.com/tobiasoberrauch/yeoman-analyzer/blob/master/lib/analyzer/generators.js#L90

Sometimes is the zip file empty, the download stops suddenly or the esprima parser shows unexpected error. But I have a rough plan to optimize it.
This is just a awful callback hell. Now it's time to optimize and restructure.